# How to earn the voting badge 'Vox Populi"?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have done quite a bit of reading, researching on this site voted here and there and then I got the recommendation from the system to earn the badge `Vox Populi` there was only 3 or 4 votes left, so I thought, let's got for it...

But the system stopped me from voting with `39/40` saying I have to wait another day since I exceeded the `voting-limit`.

I mean *fair enough*, I do not give that much on the badge, and I would never go like: "Today is the day to earn `Vox Populi`, lets do `40` votes. But I had `36` already and was just wondering, how this could happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you are voting too heavily on answers rather than questions. The vote limit at one point was 30 and when it was increased to 40, the extra 10 votes were considered to be for questions only. The full breakdown on the vote limit [can be seen here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/236364).

This limit while being awkward helps implicitly make sure questions and answers get similar votes and attention.

Comment: would be nice it sat that in the short description though, as it does for other badges...

Comment: @nath - being too focused on badges is not really the aim of the site. All of these are fully explained in faq posts on meta if people are interested, but generally badges are awarded for generally doing positive things on the site.